# Numeric feature in setup function

Tags: python, pycaret

I want to pass all my features(100+) as a numeric feature is there any method to do it without writing all features in the setup column?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a list of all the features and pass that list to setup.
Something like this:

`num_cols = data.columns().to_list()`
or
`num_cols = data.select_dtypes(include=['float64'])`

`clf = setup(data, numeric_features= num_cols, target='yourtarget')`